# How to add inline css/js inside a wordpress shortcode

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, shortcode

I'm working on creating a shortcode which is meant to change the css and js dynamically for that shortcode based on the situation. Now the problem is that I not getting a clue about how to use `add_action()` inside a `add_shortcode()`. Let me give you an example snippet code so that you guys can better understand me:

```
add_shortcode('example', function( $atts ) {
    //extracting the shortcode attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'value1' => null,
        'value2' => null, 
        'value3' => null
    ), $atts ) );

    //Now here I wll do my code for the shortcode
    // But the shortcode needs some js and css to work
    // so, I'm trying like this

    //For the CSS
    add_action('wp_head', function() {
        echo '<style type="text/css">
            .class {
                background-color: '. $value2 .';
            }
        </style>';
    });

    //For the JS
    add_action('wp_footer', function() {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            var a = '. $value3 .'
        </script>';
    });

});
```

Now obviously it is not working, so I was hoping if any of you can guide me how to the similar thing in the proper way.

If you can, please help instead of negative voting the question.

Comment: Question: Is it really necessary to have js and css in the shortcode. I would   put the css into the style.css and the javascript part into a js file

Comment: @meck373 I think you havn't read the example code properly. The reason I had to do it because the CSS & JS values will be dynamically changed based on the shortcode values. As you can see above, I have used `$value2` and `$value3` in the css & js section accordingly. Both of which is coming from the shortcode. That's why I've taken this approach. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a better way to do this, but currently to just make it work, remove the add_action() part, just make a string with your code and return it:

```
add_shortcode('example', function( $atts ) {
    //extracting the shortcode attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'value1' => null,
        'value2' => null, 
        'value3' => null
    ), $atts ) );

    //For the CSS
        $result = '<style type="text/css">
            .class {
                background-color: '. $value2 .';
            }
        </style>';

    //For the JS
        $result .= '<script type="text/javascript">
            var a = '. $value3 .'
        </script>';

    return $result;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.  But this doesn't seems a good way to do it as the style tags will get populated within the `body`. After doing a lot of research I'm taking this kind of approach: http://pastebin.com/eYi6RAbT not sure if it will work. Can you please take a look and share your thoughts on it.